# Can Deadlifts be used as a supplement to increase squats PR?

Tags: bodybuilding, squats, deadlifts, powerlifting, olympic-weightlifting

While I do BB squats I often do not have a spotter so in case of trying to get PR I find it a bit risky and hence my squats numbers are not increasing as much as I'd like to.But in case of a DL it's not much of a hassle doing alone.I was wondering if I could increase my lower body strength using DL and then it will help in squats? 
Current PR's: BB Squat 90kg,DL 100kg. BW is 62kg.

Comment: A squat should never require a spotter. For one, you should have learned to bail on a failed squat, and secondly, the squat rack should have safety bars so you can just sit down, and have the bar be taken off your shoulders.

Comment: The rack in my gym doesn't have a bar,we have to put the BB in position,walk back,do squats and then rerack. Secondly I do understand that we should understand if we'd hit failure but I am sort of stuck in a similar weight week after week so I have decided to go for one rep maxes for a few weeks as my aim is 100kgx5, currently I struggle enduring 80x5.for 5 sets.I sort of have the strength but I seem to lack the endurance or stamina.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, deadlift improvements can contribute to squat improvements.  Both of these barbell movements train the back and legs.

However, please consider ["The First Three Questions"](https://startingstrength.com/article/the_first_three_questions) whenever you see less progress than you want or expect.

By the way: The squat cannot be spotted properly by a single person; two people are required -- one for each end of the barbell.  And, if you fail a squat and the squatters help you, then *stay with the bar*; don't bail completely and leave it in their hands.